# Angular cast json string to typed array

Tags: c#, json, angular, asp.net-core

**SampleDataController:**

```
[HttpGet("GetAllItems")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllItems()
{
    return Json(await _storeContext.Table.AsQueryable().ToListAsync());
}
```

DataService:

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetAllItems() {
    return this.http.get("https://localhost:44381/api/SampleData/GetAllItems");
  }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../store.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  public itemsList: Item[];

  constructor(private logger: DataService) {}

  GetItems() {
    this.logger.GetAllItems().subscribe(
      data => this.itemsList = <Item[]>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
    )
  }
}

export interface Item {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Surname: string;
}
```

Component html:

```
<button mat-button (click)="GetItems()">GetItems!</button>

<li *ngFor="let item of itemsList">
  <span>
    <br />
    {{item.Name}}
    <br />
    {{item.Surname}}
  </span>
</li>
```

After clicking on button `GetItems()` returns array of Objects. I thought that `data => this.itemsList = <Items[]>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` should cast to array of `Item` and I should get `Item[]` array. What is proper way of casting json to typed array in TypeScript?

Json data example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "1",
        "surname": "2         "
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "1",
        "surname": "2         "
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "1",
        "surname": "2         "
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the HTTP request

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetAllItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>("https://localhost:44381/api/SampleData/GetAllItems");
  }
}
```

and do

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../store.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

    export class AppComponent {

      public itemsList: Item[];

      constructor(private logger: DataService) {}

      GetItems() {
        this.logger.GetAllItems().subscribe(
          (data: Item[]) => this.itemsList = data
        )
      }
    }

export interface Item {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Surname: string;
}
```

Anyway, there are some further recommendations. Please use common naming rules, use lowerCamelCase for methods and members. Also avoid subscribe (use async pipe instead) or at least unsubscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Ok` method instead of `Json` to return serialized objects as its more feature complete:

```
[HttpGet("GetAllItems")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllItems()
{
    return this.Ok(await _storeContext.Table.AsQueryable().ToListAsync());
}
```

In the angular side, by default a response body is assumed to contain JSON, so you can rework you service into the following [as explained in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response):

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetAllItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>("https://localhost:44381/api/SampleData/GetAllItems");
  }
}
```

Because of this, you dont need to manually de-serialize anything (eg.: using `JSON.parse`), as angular will take care of this step.